# Заблокировать редактирование конца маршрута

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Добавляю на карту маршрут стандартным образом, через MultiRoute. Но конечная точка машрута всегда одна и та-же (офис компании - не меняет положения), начальную же имеет смысл двигать.

Однако если разрешить редактирование маршрута то двигать можно обе точки.

Как программно запертить редактирование только одной точки маршрута?

Comment: програмно переставляй конец маршрута обратно в офис перед каждым перестоением.

Answer (score 0):

Такой пример есть в документации API Яндекс.Карт:
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_panel_control

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.753994, 37.622093],
        zoom: 9,
        // Добавим панель маршрутизации.
        controls: ['routePanelControl']
    });

    var control = myMap.controls.get('routePanelControl');

    // Зададим состояние панели для построения машрутов.
    control.routePanel.state.set({
        // Тип маршрутизации.
        type: 'masstransit',
        // Включим возможность задавать пункт отправления в поле ввода.
        fromEnabled: true,
        // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
        to: 'Москва, Льва Толстого 16',
        // Выключим возможность задавать пункт назначения в поле ввода.
        toEnabled: false
        // Адрес или координаты пункта назначения.
    });
```

Comment: Такой метод не подходит, потому что панели роутинга у меня как раз и нет. Ее можно бы было использовать на десктопе но на мобильных она занимает слишком много места.

Answer (score 0):

Ловите [`beforewaypointdragstart`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/multiRouter.Editor-docpage/#event_detail__event_detail/event-beforewaypointdragstart) на редакторе и отменяйте его через [`preventDefault`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/Event-docpage/#method_detail__preventDefault):

```
multiRoute.editor.events.add('beforewaypointdragstart', (event) => {
    const wayPoint = event.get('wayPoint');
    if (!canEdit(wayPoint)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```